# Selenium Webdriver & Java : require help in If else logic

Tags: selenium

After clicking on the search button on the homepage, when it lands on the fare details page, I want that when the Fare cost is below 9000, then it should click on the continue button.

Refer to the Code is below

```
public class MySelenium {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\kunal.bhaskar\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        // Form filling on www.spicejet.com     
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            String baseUrl = "http://www.spicejet.com";
            driver.get(baseUrl);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_mainContent_chk_IndArm\"]")).click();
           driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          WebElement dep = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTXT\"]"));
          dep.click();
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          dep.sendKeys("Bengaluru");
          WebElement arr = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_mainContent_ddl_destinationStation1_CTXT\"]"));
          arr.click();
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          arr.sendKeys("Patna");
          WebElement date1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"flightSearchContainer\"]/div[3]/button"));
          date1.click();
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
              //click the button
              WebElement arrow = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-datepicker-div\"]/div[2]/div/a/span"));
              arrow.click();

             }
          WebElement arr1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-datepicker-div\"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/a"));
          arr1.click();
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

          WebElement dep1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-datepicker-div\"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[7]/a"));
          dep1.click();
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


        Select curr1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_mainContent_DropDownListCurrency\"]")));
        curr1.selectByVisibleText("INR");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_mainContent_btn_FindFlights\"]")).click();

        WebElement rate = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"taxAndFeeInclusiveDivBody\"]/h4[1]/span[1]"));

         if (rate < 9000) {
             driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"continue-to-contact-page\"]/span[1]")).click();
         }
   }     
}
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the HTML of `Continue` button? I guess you are trying to locate it through `(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"continue-to-contact-page\"]/span[1]"))`

Comment: Yes, what's wrong with xpath

Comment: While Answering back to my comment you have skipped the main question about relevant `HTML` of `Continue` button. Too early to comment on your `xpath` !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in spicejet.com, rate is in Float value. So you can replace below line

if (Float.parseFloat(rate.getText().replaceAll(",", "")) < 9000)

Comment: Done. There is a checkbox, after clicking the checkbox then continue button got enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The rate object is of type ***WebElement***. You have to extract the text data and  convert it to **Integer** type for performing comparisons.

The if condition should look like this :

```
 if (Integer.parseInt(rate.getText()) < 9000) {
```

Comment: I have done that but still its not clicking on the button continue